# Add extra value to array from getArrayResult()

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a query that fetches entities from the database. One of the fields is "filename". My model is also aware of the web path and has a function "getPath()" which returns the filename with the relevant path.

At the moment, my array is returned as follows:

```
Array
    (
        [id] => 359
        [thumb] => sound_thumb.png
        ...
    )
```

But I would like it to be like this:

```
Array
    (
        [id] => 359
        [thumb] => sound_thumb.png
        [path] => /path/to/file/sound_thumb.png
        ...
    )
```

Is there any way to achieve this using `$query->getArrayResult();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you would have to do this in your entity directly. There is a great section [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) about file uploads (the code below is extracted from this section, and is what I usually use to handle file path in my entities). Basically, you could add a `getAbsolutePath()` method that you can call to obtain the absolute path of your thumb.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
public $path;

public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->path
        ? null
        : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
}

public function getWebPath()
{
    return null === $this->path
        ? null
        : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
}

protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
    // the absolute directory path where uploaded
    // thumbs should be saved
    return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
}

protected function getUploadDir()
{
    // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
    // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
    return 'uploads/thumbs';
}
```

Now, you need to return an array of objects in your query and you'll be able to access the absolute path by calling `$object->getAbsolutePath()`.

### Edit

If you really need to return an array using `$query->getArrayResult()`:

<kbd>1</kbd> Create a property `$absolutePath`

<kbd>2</kbd> Update `$absolutePath` every time you change the path, using prePersist and preUpdate [lifecycle events](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events).

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
public $absolutePath;

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function updateAbsolutePath()
{
    $this->absolutePath = $this->getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Now, you should have:

```
Array
    (
        [id] => 359
        [thumb] => sound_thumb.png
        [path] => sound_thumb.png
        [absolutePath] => /path/to/file/sound_thumb.png
        ...
    )
```

Comment: I've used that guide to upload files and have those functions in my Entity. However the problem is that I need my objects as an array, not as objects. That's why I was doing getArrayResult() instead of getResult(). At the moment, I have a dummy object, call the getUploadDir() function and use that, while looping over the objects to set the path...

Comment: Thank you, I like your answer, however storing the paths in db is something I'd rather not do. I'm gonna wait and see if anyone comes up with anything else. Otherwise I'll just do it like this...

Comment: Sure. I totally understand your point. I wouldn't return an array in that case because you are losing all the info stored in your model. You lose all the methods that do the extra work. A clean way IMO is to return an object. Returning an array will limit yourself to the properties, which is quite annoying. You can also return an object, and then call `$object->toArray()` if you absolutely need to convert the object. Good luck @Bram.

Comment: @Bram I face similar issue. I am thinking of doing as explain by Patt (using lifecycleevent to update the property absolutpath) but in you comment you seems to want to avoid this solution. Is there a risk or a probleme doing such? (how have to dealt with it finnaly?)